# Get clicked cell in gridview asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I got gridview that I fill with data from my database. I would like to catch an event of click and to get attributes of the cell row and column.

all I found is row click that I can get the row clicked.
also, if there is other component to deploy the data and can get me the cell click event is good enough for me.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="grid">
    <asp:GridView ID="HistoricGrid" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
</div>
```

**C#**

```
DBconnection db = new DBconnection();
string strtable = "select * from StudentVisit";
DataTable dt = db.ReadDataTable(strtable);
HistoricGrid.DataSource = dt; HistoricGrid.DataBind();
```

thanks for the help,
Moshe

Comment: show your gridview markup.

Comment: html: <div class="grid">
                <asp:GridView ID="HistoricGrid" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
            </div>
c#:DBconnection db = new DBconnection();
            string strtable = "select * from StudentVisit";
            DataTable dt = db.ReadDataTable(strtable);
            HistoricGrid.DataSource = dt;
            HistoricGrid.DataBind();
I created DB connection class to handle all DB connection with entity framework. I populate the grid with the datatable returned

Answer (score 0):

You should try this.

```
   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowHeader="True" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
     <Columns>
      <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Value" DataField="ItemValue" ReadOnly="true" />
      <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Text" DataField="ItemText" ReadOnly="true" />
      <asp:TemplateField>
       <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
       </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
     </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

aspx.cs file

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
 if ( e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow )
 {
  LinkButton linkButton = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("LinkButton1");

  if (linkButton != null)
  {
   linkButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.open('someURL'); return false;");
  }
 }
```

}

Comment: but I don't have button inside my grid cell. and I populate it with data table bonded to the grid.datasource.
any option not use button? I also don't know the actual size of the grid. it's depend on the data returned from DB

Answer (score -1):

You can use below code

```
private void gv_Cell_Click(object sender, GridViewCellEventArgs e)
       {
           int cellindex=e.CellIndex;
           int rowindex =e.rowindex;
           var value = gv.Rows[rowindex].Cells[cellindex].value;

       }
```

Comment: where  to register gv_Cell_Click event hander for the gridview gv?